# Add edges within one traversal using Gremlin

Tags: graph, traversal, gremlin, titan, edges

we have:

```
g = graph.traversal()
```

What I what to do is like:

```
numV = g.V().count()
g.V().range(0,numV-1).addE('label').to(g.V().range(1,numV))
```

I want to add out edges between two adjacent vertices.

In my case, numV is calculated using a long code instead of simple g.V().count(), also g.V() in the second line will be replaced by a long line, so there are two questions:

1. How to avoid pre-compute numV? as we have already done g.V() in the second line of the code.
2. I tried to simplify the code like this:

   ```
   g.V().as('a').range(0,numV-1).addE('label').to(select('a').range(1,numV))
   ```

   but it gives me error:

   > The provided traverser does not map to a value

I am kind of new to Gremlin.

Comment: Do you want to connect vertex `n` with vertex `n + 1` or with all other vertices (`n+1..numV`)? It would help tremendously if you could provide a small sample graph.

Comment: Yep, I just need to connect vertex n with vertex n + 1, and n should be in range (0,size-1), inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a small sample graph that consists of `foo` and `bar` vertices and sequential IDs.

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.withSack(1).
......1>   addV('foo').
......2>     property(id, sack()).
......3>   emit().
......4>     repeat(sack(sum).by(constant(1)).
......5>            addV().
......6>              property(label, __.constant(['foo','bar']).sample(local, 1).unfold()).
......7>              property(id, sack())).
......8>     times(20).
......9>   valueMap(true)
==>[label:foo,id:1]
==>[label:foo,id:2]
==>[label:bar,id:3]
==>[label:foo,id:4]
==>[label:bar,id:5]
==>[label:bar,id:6]
==>[label:foo,id:7]
==>[label:foo,id:8]
==>[label:foo,id:9]
==>[label:bar,id:10]
==>[label:foo,id:11]
==>[label:bar,id:12]
==>[label:foo,id:13]
==>[label:bar,id:14]
==>[label:bar,id:15]
==>[label:foo,id:16]
==>[label:bar,id:17]
==>[label:bar,id:18]
==>[label:foo,id:19]
==>[label:foo,id:20]
==>[label:bar,id:21]
```

Now let's say that we want to connect all `foo` vertices with a `baz` edge; the order criteria will be the vertex id.

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('foo').
......1>   order().
......2>     by(id).as('a').
......3>   aggregate('x').
......4>   flatMap(select('x').unfold().
......5>             where(gt('a')).by(id).
......6>             limit(1)).
......7>   addE('baz').
......8>     from('a')
==>e[0][1-baz->2]
==>e[1][2-baz->4]
==>e[2][4-baz->7]
==>e[3][7-baz->8]
==>e[4][8-baz->9]
==>e[5][9-baz->11]
==>e[6][11-baz->13]
==>e[7][13-baz->16]
==>e[8][16-baz->19]
==>e[9][19-baz->20]
```

I think that's pretty much the scenario you're looking for, but it's hard to tell without a provided sample graph and an expected outcome.

Also note, that you should always have an explicit order criterion (it doesn't have to be the id), otherwise TinkerPop won't guarantee a deterministic order.